My Opportunity Test Class is not calling the Opportunity Trigger that executes Opportunity Trigger Handler Class with Helper Class
I implemented the Trigger Framework.
This is my Opportunity Trigger
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before update, after update, before delete{
    new OpportunityTriggerHandler().run();
}

Opportunity Trigger Handler Class that extends Trigger Handler Class by Kevin Ohara
public with sharing class OpportunityTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler{

   public override void beforeInsert(){
        OpportunityHelper.setOppType(Trigger.new);
   }
}

This is my Opportunity Helper method
public static void setOppType(List<Opportunity> newRecords){
    for(Opportunity opp : newRecords){
        opp.Type = opp.Type == null ? 'New Customer' : opp.Type;
    }
}

When I'm executing my below Test Class,
@IsTest
private static void testAnotherOpportunityTrigger_setType() {
    Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
    insert acc;
    
    Integer numberOfOpps = 5;
    for (Integer i = 0; i < numberOfOpps; i++) {
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
            Name = 'Test Opportunity ' + i,
            StageName = 'Prospecting',
            CloseDate = Date.today(),
            AccountId = acc.Id
        );
        insert opp;
     }
    
     List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT Id, Name, Type FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :acc.Id];
     System.assertEquals(numberOfOpps, opps.size(), 'Number of Opportunities created is incorrect.');
     for (Opportunity opp : opps) {
         System.assertEquals('New Customer', opp.Type, 'Opportunity ' + opp.Name + ' Type is incorrect.');
     }

the test class is failing with the below error.

TriggerBestPracticeTest.testAnotherOpportunityTrigger_setType  AccountHelper       Fail     79%      System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Opportunity Test Opportunity 0 Type is incorrect.: Expected: New Customer, Actual: null
Class.TriggerBestPracticeTest.testAnotherOpportunityTrigger_setType: line 279, column 1                                            889
TriggerBestPracticeTest.testAnotherOpportunityTrigger_setType  AccountTrigger      Fail     100%     System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Opportunity Test Opportunity 0 Type is incorrect.: Expected: New Customer, Actual: null
Class.TriggerBestPracticeTest.testAnotherOpportunityTrigger_setType: line 279, column 1

Can anyone please help me where am I doing it wrong?
I'm seeing the Classes that are failing are of Account Trigger and its Helper Class which executes upon account insertion in the test class but they are executing fine. Couldn't figure out on this. Help me understand to solve this, please.


Your trigger is calling OpportunityTriggerHandler().run(), but is your run() method calling your beforeInsert() method?

Add System.debug statements inside of your Trigger, Handler, and Helper to understand where the trigger execution is falling off. I've implemented Kevin O'Hara before and, generally speaking everything looks mostly right except you are missing a ) in your Trigger which I assume is just a typo on StackExchange since the trigger wouldn't compile with that missing ).

Also make sure you actually activated your new trigger :)

By the way, the new null coalescing operator can make your code simpler: opp.Type = opp.Type ?? 'New Customer';

@MorganMarchese Yes, it is a typo here and the trigger is active. I cross-checked in the .xml file.

@DerekF I'm using this source code as is without any changes, where the run() method dispatches the correct trigger context
TriggerHandlerFramework - https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework/blob/master/src/classes/TriggerHandler.cls

I added the Test Class failed message in the question. It says that the Test Class failed for the Classes 'Account Helper' and 'Account Trigger' which I assume are being called when Account record is inserted in the Test Class.
But those Account Triggers and Helper Classes passed the Test when I tested but failing when testing the Opportunity Trigger. How do I make sure it passes ?

Add the before insert context to your trigger.
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before insert, before update, after update, before delete{
  new OpportunityTriggerHandler().run();
}

